# Cordova: Missing package.windows80.appmanifest after upgrade

Tags: windows, cordova

I couldn't find this issue anywhere, nor is the error very detailed.

I have a project which was build on cordova 5.4.1 (or something) and I used the windows8 platform. At least that's how it's configured.

Now I've installed the latest cordova

```
npm install -g cordova@latest
```

and afterwards I did

```
cordova platform remove windows
cordova platform add windows
```

Most of it seemed to work fine but I get the following output

```
$ cordova platform add windows

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Adding windows project...
Creating Cordova Windows Project:
        Path: platforms\windows
        Namespace: com.someclient.someclientproject
        Name: Client Project
Windows project created with cordova-windows@4.4.3
Installing "cordova-fabric-plugin" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for windows
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for windows
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mathijs\projects\someclientproject\platforms\windows\package.windows80.appxmanifest'
```

The file indeed is missing, there are some other packages though like windows10 etc.

Does anyone have any idea what could be off?

Also, this also occurs on running any command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end;

Check your cordova version, check your SDK version it's probably misconfigured which was the case for me.

Comment: Hello @Mathijs Segers I've got the same problem now, I've removed and reinstalled cordova, using 6.5.0 and installed windows platform again.
Also I've downloaded the latest SDK with no success. Which SDK did you install to get it working again?

Comment: I think it was 6.1 but to be honest I don't remember, nor am I working with cordova nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I too got

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[...]/platforms/windows/package.windows80.appxmanifest'
```

while running `cordova platform add windows` with the latest Cordova (7.0.1). I tracked the issue down to my install of [cordova-plugin-customurlscheme](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme), specifically the `src/windows/hooks/prepare-manifest.js` file which lists four Windows platforms for manifest updating. I'm building only for Windows 10, so my solution was to remove the unneeded platforms so the file looks like this:

```
[/*MANIFEST_PHONE, MANIFEST_WINDOWS80, MANIFEST_WINDOWS,*/ MANIFEST_WINDOWS10]
.forEach(function(manifestFile) {
    updateManifestFile(path.join(projectRoot, manifestFile));
});
```